# Trying to get all records in one table that have data in another table and summarize them

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MYSQL tables

Table 1 has an ID and a NAME

Table 2 has the same ID and a DATE and a TIME column that reflects when the ID was visited - maybe 100s of times a day.

I am trying to display

```
ID    Name     Date          Number of Calls
 1     Name1    2020-01-01           131
 1     Name1    2020-01-02           112
 2     Name2    2020-01-01             3
18     Name18   2020-01-01           212
18     Name18   2020-01-03            16
68     Name68   2020-11-09           716
```

And so on.

Any help would be appreciated.

My code at present is:

```
SELECT propid, COUNT(pdate),
pdate
FROM propviews
GROUP BY propid, pdate
ORDER BY propid,
COUNT(propid) DESC;
```

Just don't know where to put a join in in this select statement

Comment: What's the problem? Use JOIN, COUNT(*), and GROUP BY.

Comment: I am doing all of those - just don't know where to put a JOIN in to Table 1

SELECT propid, COUNT(pdate),
pdate
FROM propviews
GROUP BY propid, pdate
ORDER BY propid,
COUNT(propid) DESC;

Comment: `FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id`

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `JOIN` with the table containing the names.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, v.date, COUNT(*) AS number_of_calls
FROM prop AS p
JOIN propviews AS v on p.id = v.propid
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, v.date
ORDER BY p.id, number_of_calls DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I got it - just need that little light to go on is all!!

SELECT f1, f2, f3, COUNT(f3)
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON f1 = f4
GROUP BY f1, f3
ORDER BY f1 ASC;

Thanks again.